# Regex hora customizada em python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Estou precisando criar uma regex que aceite as seguintes entradas:

```
8:00  
8 horas    
8h   
8h30 (8h 30)  
8h30min (8h 30 min)  
8h30minutos (8h 30 minutos)
```

e eu cheguei na seguinte:

```
((\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) | (\d{1,2}\s+\bhoras\b) | (\d{1,2}\bh\b(\s+\d{1,2}(\bminutos\b|\bmin\b)?)?))?
```

As duas primeiras partes funcionam separadamente, quando as junto com um | não funciona. A terceira parte não funciona de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Só pra esclarecer, as horas entre parênteses são apenas outras maneiras de expressar a regex que vem antes. A diferença é o acréscimo de espaços em branco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Porque sua regex não funciona**
Você cometeu diversos erros nela, isso acontece com quem está começando, não vou somente mostrar onde errou mas sim explicar um jeito melhor que espero que siga daqui pra frente, assim suas regex não vão mais falhar.

- **Adicionar espaços ao fim da regex no separador OU** (`|`), sei que isso deixa a regex mais legível e facil de entender, mas é por isso que ela não funcionou com as outras alternativas que você colocou, quando ela analisava as sequencias após o separador OU, verificava se a sequencia era iniciada com espaço.
- **Uso desnecessário de word separator** (`\b`), faz a análise da sequencia como uma palavra, esperando o último caractere válido e verifica se ele bate perfeitamente com seu padrão ou seja, quando você usava **h** ele só encontraria " h ", se ele tivesse seguido por um número ou outra letra não capturaria.
- **"?" Após o grupo de captura** ( `)?` ), você esta fazendo com que a regex só capture 0 ou 1 vez esse grupo, então caso a sua regex funcionasse pra 1 sequencia, ela ia parar por aí.
- **Um grupo de captura para cada caso**, a regex que você apresentou tem um grupo de captura para cada caso, sendo que é plausível pensar que um número após a sequencia "`h` , `hora` ou `:`" é o número de minuto, então simplesmente adicione a palavra minuto após as sequencias com `h` ou `hora` e isso vai te poupar tempo de processamento e elaboração da regex.

**Regex que funciona para seus casos**

```
(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})|(\d{1,2}\s+horas{0,1})|(\d{1,2}h ?\d{0,2})
```

[Você pode testar o funcionamento dessa regex aqui](https://regex101.com/r/vxswBp/2/)

Comment: Deu certo sim, resposta perfeita. Valeu!